# Door Slamming Against Wall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, drag

There is a door with length $r$ and mass $m$ hinged on a wall with angle $\theta$, and an equally distributed gust of wind with constant velocity $v$ pushing on that door in the direction normal to the wall, as shown in the drawing:

[image]

I wish to find a function of $\theta$ by time. This is what I made of it so far (as someone with no experience in physics):

According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNL5w73owzU&t=90s) video, for a fluid acting normally on a wall, the force is:
$$F = v_a^2\cdot \rho\cdot A$$
Where $\rho$ is the fluid density and $A$ is the area on which the fluid hits the wall. I have silently replaced $A$ with $L$ (representing length) in my calculations since the problem here is 2 dimensional instead of 3. However, I am not sure I can do this.
So since the wind is acting down, the force vector is: $ \newcommand\mycolv[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}
$
$$\overrightarrow{F}=\mycolv{0\\-L\rho \cdot v_a^2}$$
However the wind is not normal to the door. So taking the vector normal to the door, that is
$$\mycolv{\cos(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})\\ \sin(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})}$$
and taking the dot product with the force vector to get the part that is normal to the door, we get:

$$F_n=-L\rho \cdot v_a^2\cdot \sin(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})$$
L is the projection of the door onto the wall, since the wind hits normal to the wall. Meaning:
$$F_n=-r \cos(\theta)\rho \cdot v_a^2\cdot \sin(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})$$
Simplifying, we finally get:
$$F_n=r \rho \cdot v_a^2\cdot \cos^2(\theta)$$
So:
$$F=ma \Longrightarrow r \rho \cdot v_a^2\cdot \cos^2(\theta)=m\ddot{\theta}$$
And we reach the ODE:
$$\ddot{\theta} = \frac{r \rho  v_a^2}{m}\cdot \cos^2(\theta)$$
Which, while to my knowledge cannot be solved using standard mathematical functions, provides a satisfying enough answer for me.

When I spoke to my physics teacher about this however, he approached it differently. First he said he didn't think my method would work, because "the moment changes with time". I assume he's referring to moment of inertia. He then approximated the motion of the rotating door with a point particle which was traveling in a straight line. He said this was a standard method of approximation, some term with the word circular. And while the answer he gave is (according to him) a good approximation, I would like to know if my "answer" is the completely correct one, and if not, what is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve computed the *force* on the door, which would give you the acceleration of the door’s center of mass if the wind were the only force involved.  But it’s not.  The door is attached to a hinge, which is exerting some complicated additional force so that the door’s center of mass moves in a circle around the hinge.

You want to find the *torque* $\tau$ on the door, and then use the relation

$$\tau = I\ddot\theta$$

to find the angular acceleration $\ddot\theta$.

The moment of inertia $I$ for the door does not change as it rotates about its end.  (The moment of inertia is $I = fmr^2$, where $m$ is the mass of the door, $r$ is the width, and $f$ is a fraction that comes from an integral which everyone does as a sophomore but immediately forgets and [looks up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) when they need it again.)

You have correctly found that the force goes like $\cos\theta$ [which you have written as $\sin\left(\theta-\pi/2\right)$], and that the lever arm associated with the torque also goes like $\cos\theta$, so you’ll have $\tau \propto \ddot\theta \propto \cos^2\theta$.  But you’ve got the constants of proportionality wrong.  Choosing the middle of the door for the lever arm, and switching to the moment of inertia, introduces a factor which I think is either $2/3$ or $6$, but I haven’t done the algebra to decide which.

Also,

> I have silently replaced $A$
> with $L$
> (representing length) […] However, I am not sure I can do this.

The area of the door is its width times its height.  Your expression is for a “force per unit height,” with units $\text{newton}/\text{meter}$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Some questions that arise from this for me are: 1. Why choose the middle of the door for the lever arm? Why not the end? 2. It seems (according to your linked wiki page) that the moment of inertia in this case is I=m(L^2)/3. And you seem to have implicitly said that what I calculated as "Fn" is actually the torque. So the correct answer would be to say that theta double dot=3Fn/(mL^2)?

Comment: 1. Do a sum-or-integral over all the little bits of force on all the little bits of door. 2. I think the torque goes like $r^2$: one factor from the lever arm, and one from the magnitude of the force. You seem to have a definition for $L$ which is different from the width of the door.

Comment: Sorry, when I said $L^2$ I meant $r^2$, I was just looking at the wiki page which used $L$. But in any case, If $\tau = F_n = I \ddot{\theta}$, and if the moment of inertia is $\frac{1}{3}mr^2$ (which maps to case 4 in the Wikipedia list), then you simply divide by $I$ and get that $\ddot{\theta} = 3\frac{\rho v_a^2}{mr}\cdot cos^2(\theta)$?

Comment: Your fraction $\frac{\rho v^2}{mr}$ has units $\rm m^{-2}\,s^{-2}$, but $\ddot\theta$ should have units $\rm s^{-2}$. So your expression is incorrect. I won't solve your problem for you, because of [our policy on homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714). However you might visit [chat] and ask politely if anyone there will help your walk through the gory details.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Take the sum of the torque about the point A you obtain

$$I_A\,\ddot\theta-\frac 12 F\,r=0\tag 1$$

where

$$I_A=I_{\text{CM}}+m\,\left(\frac r2\right)^2\\
F=v^2\,\cos^2(\theta)\,\rho\,A=v^2\,\cos^2(\theta)\,\rho\,r\,b$$

- I is the door Inertia
- b is the door width
- CM center of mass